# RxJava create buffer with item count skip and timespan

Tags: buffer, rx-java

I noticed that in RxJava we are not able to perform operations such as this method signature `buffer(count, skip, timespan, TimeUnit)`

Is there anyway to perform this operations without recreating another operation for buffer.

this [method](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer(rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func1)) doesn't help a lot. Beside, in the doc there is no spec if it emits overlapping buffered items or not !??

**UPDATE**

What flatMapIterable adds here ? The desired behaviour is that if a have 10 items in the specified timespan then a buffered item is emitted. if the timespan has elapsed and no item is emitted i want to receive an empty buffer.

using the count and skip oblige to wait until the count is reached but returns nothing in between.

Comment: What do you mean by not recreating another operation for buffer ? not creating a new operator or not calling buffer again ? 

(btw, a naive workaround : `obs.buffer(timestamp, timeunit).flatMapIterable(i -> i).buffer(count, skip)`)

Comment: obs.buffer(timestamp, timeunit) ??? do you mean timespan ?

Comment: yeap. small typo error

Comment: What flatMapIterable adds here ? The desired behaviour is that if a have n = 10 with a skip of 5 items in the specified timespan then a buffered item is emitted. if the timespan has elapsed and no item is emitted i want to receive an empty buffer.

using the count and skip oblige to wait until the count is reached but returns nothing in between.